# docker mount nfs with local_lock=all

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, nfs

I have docker-compose.yml file

```
volumes:
  nfs:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: addr=192.168.100.1,rw
        device: ":/mnt/storage"
```

my container have mounted volume with options:

```
type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.100.1,mountvers=3,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.100.1)
```

with **local_lock=none** and i can't change this option to **local_lock=all**
I tried:

```
volumes:
  nfs:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: addr=192.168.100.1,rw,local_lock=all
        device: ":/mnt/storage"
```

and

```
volumes:
  nfs:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: addr=192.168.100.1,rw
        device: ":/mnt/storage"
        local_lock: all
```

but nothing changes

Comment: If it's any syntax, it would be the first one with `o: addr=192.168.100.1,rw,local_lock=all`. Did you delete and recreate the volume with that setting configured?

Comment: @BMitch I realize that this issue might be coming from Linux/Ubuntu/NFS and not Docker itself. If I try to manually mount my volume in Ubuntu with `mount -o nfsvers=4,nolock ...`, I still see `local_lock=none` in the `mount`output. Is it an Ubuntu issue? Or NFS 4?

Comment: @alexpirine docker is just going to pass that option through to the OS and NFS driver, so that's a strong possibility.

Comment: @BMitch yep (see edited comment). The issue is that inside the docker instances, I have "no locks available" error messages. Everything works as expected directly on the host. So, for some reason NFS locks don't work inside Docker containers… And no way to ignore them since the `local_lock=all` option is ignored.

Comment: @alexpirine `local_lock` is listed as an nfs 2 or 3 only option in my man page. So if you're using nfs4 that may not work.

Comment: @BMitch thank you! The author of the question probably used nfs4 too. I'm checking if adding some nfs tools to docker images solves the "no locks available" issue.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that doesn't answer the question is to create NFS mounts directly on the host, and then export the mounted folder to a docker volume. This way, NFS locks are no longer required on Docker containers.

Not an ideal solution for Docker Swarm, since it requires maintaining NFS mounts on each node of the swarm.

Comment: clusterssh for a fixed number of VMs could help or ansible to setup vms

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you want is the first option:

```
volumes:
  nfs:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: addr=192.168.100.1,rw,local_lock=all
        device: ":/mnt/storage"
```

That is just a pass through to the OS. The reason you likely don't see any difference with that volume mount is that `local_lock` is listed as an NFS 2 or NFS 3 only option, so if you're using NFS 4 that option is likely ignored.

Comment: Hmm, this is the correct answer but doesn't solve the issue, unfortunately… Any way to use local locks in NFS 4?

Comment: I don't believe this is a supported feature in nfs4. If you need this option, you'll need to downgrade.